# AWS PHP for describeVolumes

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am having some trouble pulling the volume name in the Tags section using the Amazon PHP SDK.

I'm able to print the Volume ID but since the Tags are in a separate array, I am not sure how to reference the value of the Key called 'Name'.

```
$east_client = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($east_config);
$east_result = $east_client->describeVolumes();
$east_volumes =  $east_result['Volumes'];

foreach ($east_volumes as $e)
{
      echo $e['VolumeId'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the API docs for `describeVolumes()` in case you haven't seen them: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_describeVolumes.

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($volumes as $volume) {
    echo "{$volume['VolumeId']}\n";
    foreach ($volume['Tags'] as $tag) {
        echo "- {$tag['Key']}: {$tag['Value']}\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```